# Android SDKs sucking up my hard drive

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

My app supports Android 4.x all they way through 7.x.  As a result, I have all API revs between 14 & 26 installed on my machine.  All those API rev's combined are taking up nearly 100Gb on my hard drive.

1. Do I need all revs still?  Does API v25 have everything need to support Android 4.1 (Rev16)?
2. If I don't need all those lower Revs and I can delete them is there a proper method for permanently removing them from my harddrive?  The SDK Manager allows you to Delete specific packages...but does deleting them via the SDK Manager actually delete them from the computer or must I do that separately?

Answer (score 1):

They only one you need is the one you are targeting and/or the versions your physical device has for instant run, if you don't use instant run in android studio then you just need the version your app is targeting